# CDC DrawDragRect Equivalent

Tags: c#, graphics

I am porting some code from c++ to c#. I have looked around and I can't find a simple equivalent to DrawDragRect in C#. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame
```

The main difference is the need to make 2 calls - one with old rect and one with new.  `CDC::DrawDragRect` did both in one call.